# Uniform sampling around hemisphere

Tags: probability, montecarlo

suppose that rand() can generate random value in [0, 1] uniformly. Is the direction of the ray generated by the following method uniformly distributed? (I am doing monte carlo integration.)

```
X = rand() * 2 - 1
Y = rand() * 2 - 1
Z = rand()

vec3 dir = vec3(X, Y, Z).normalized()
```

Comment: Try this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by myself

This method can produce sample points uniformly in the cube. but after the normalization, there're different number of points projected on the surface of the hemisphere. thus, p(x) is not a constant